# On Convergence in probability does not imply convergence in mean

Tags: convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I got the following question [Example 7.11](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_6_convergence_in_mean.php)
My questions are:

- To solve the part a, I tried to use Markov's inequality. However, it fails to show that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ since expected value of $X_n$ is $n$. Why is that?
- Why is it true that $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) = \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} P(X_n = n^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any fixed positive $\varepsilon$, we have the equality of the events
$$\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geqslant \varepsilon\right\}=\left\{X_n= n^2\right\}$$
if $n^2\geqslant \varepsilon$. Indeed, consider such an $n$. If $\left|X_n\right|\geqslant \varepsilon$, then we necessarily have $X_n=n^2$. Conversely, if $X_n=n^2$, then $X_n\geqslant \varepsilon$. 
Now, to conclude, note that for $n\geqslant \sqrt \varepsilon$, 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\left|X_n\right|\geqslant \varepsilon\right\}=\mathbb P\left\{X_n= n^2\right\}= \frac 1n.$$

Comment: Hi Davide, Can you give some insights on the first part. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the last line of my post answer the question?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking to apply Markov's inequality. My question is: Can we use Markov's inequality to solve the same?

Comment: It is possible (but not with $X_n$, maybe with $ X_n ^{1/4}$ or something like this.